# Ternary operator ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why does this not work :

```
params[:mobile].nil? ? redirect_to home_path : render nothing: true, status: 200
```

Works in all other case ternary like :

```
if_this_is_a_true_value ? then_the_result_is_this : else_it_is_this
```

Can anybody see something I'm not seeing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby is getting confused by the spaces . If you rewrite your method calls to use parentheses it will work:

```
params[:mobile].nil? ? redirect_to(home_path) : render(nothing: true, status: 200)
```

Comment: Or, just use the much more readable `if`/`then`/`else` instead of the obtuse conditional operator, which just so happens to have the correct precedence so that everything just works: `if params[:mobile].nil? then redirect_to home_path else render nothing: true, status: 200 end`